# Ошибка с Python3 Windows

Tags: python, windows

Я не знаю как сформулировать вопрос но вот такая ошибка на Windows с Python. Дело в том что такой вывод получается даже когда сам питон удалён. Версия последняя.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Изначально мне нужно было воспользоваться pip и мне помогло такое обращение:

```
$py -m pip
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте поискать упоминания о питоне в свойстве системы, в параметрах виртуального окружения может остались какие то не удалённые хвосты и перезагрузитесь

Comment: Очистил appdata от файлов питона, позже сделал поиск по файлам и ничего не нашёл, перезапустил и проблема никуда не делась